# What Java datatype can I use for MY SQL TinyInt

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I am confused with this documentation
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

TINYINT     java.lang.Boolean if the configuration property tinyInt1isBit is set to true (the default) **and the storage size is 1**, or java.lang.Integer if not.

I have this in entity class

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT default 0")
private boolean tcheck;
```

I see this in DB

```
tcheck TINYINT default 0,
```

> The numeric precision column is 3.

***I think this means storage is 3 ?***

Can I change private boolean tcheck; ===> to ===> java.lang.Integer?

I use flyway, so dont want to risk application start/corrupt db (or) updates to column width.[as size 3 is good enough]

I am assuming that changing to java.lang.Integer will not require update DB column. IS this correct?

please advice

Comment: In mysql you can use TINYINT to store boolean 0 or 1. It has a range of -128 to 127 when unsigned. It is an integer.

Comment: I created an enum and used @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL), and looks ok